How to resolve CORS issue with Laravel when Access-Control-Allow-Credentials header is not set correctly?
I'm encountering a CORS issue with my Laravel application. I have a custom CORS middleware (OwnCors) that I'm using to handle CORS requests. Despite configuring it to allow credentials, I'm facing an issue where the Access-Control-Allow-Credentials header is not set correctly.
Here's my OwnCors middleware class:
class OwnCors
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse)  $next
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true"); 

        $headers = [
            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' => 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' => 'Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, Origin, Authorization'
        ];
        if ($request->getMethod() == "OPTIONS") {
            return response('OK')
                ->withHeaders($headers);
        }

        $response = $next($request);
        foreach ($headers as $key => $value)
            $response->header($key, $value);
        return $response;
    }
}

And here's my CORS configuration (config/cors.php):
<?php

return [
    
    'paths' => ['api/*', 'api/admin/*','*'],

    'allowed_methods' => ['POST', 'GET', 'DELETE', 'PUT', '*'],

    'allowed_origins' => ['http://localhost:3000','https://personaltrainerkmm.com','https://traning-app.vercel.app','*'],

    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

    'exposed_headers' => [],

    'max_age' => 0,

    'supports_credentials' => true, 

];

Despite setting 'supports_credentials' => true, the Access-Control-Allow-Credentials header in the response is not being set correctly. Instead, it's empty.
I'm making requests from a frontend hosted on https://fitnesspt.personaltrainerkmm.com to a backend hosted on https://personaltrainerkmm.com.
How can I ensure that Laravel properly sets the Access-Control-Allow-Credentials header to true in the response to resolve this CORS issue?
Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

You should configure CORS in at most one place, preferably with a proven middleware rather than implementing it yourself. I recommend you get rid of OwnCors and solely rely on the config in config/cors.php instead. Also, note that, if your frontend has origin https://fitnesspt.personaltrainerkmm.com, you'll need to list that as an allowed origin; https://personaltrainerkmm.com won't do.

i do that , i face the same error
''' Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://personaltrainerkmm.com/api/admin/login' from origin 'https://fitnesspt.personaltrainerkmm.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is '' which must be 'true' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.'''

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class OwnCors
{
       /**
       * Handle an incoming request.
       *
       * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request):     (\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response)  $next
       */
       public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): Response
       {
             return $next($request)
                    ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
                    ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS')
                    ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With, Content-Type, X-Token-Auth, Authorization');
       }
}

To load this piece of middleware, we’ll need to add a line to app/Http/Kernel.php’s $routeMiddleware array:
'own.cors' => \App\Http\Middleware\OwnCors::class,

Also, we’ll have to add it to the $middleware array as we did for the previous middleware:
\App\Http\Middleware\OwnCors::class,


i do that , i face the same error ''' Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'personaltrainerkmm.com/api/admin/login' from origin 'fitnesspt.personaltrainerkmm.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in the response is '' which must be 'true' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.'''
